# What type of input would slow down execution time of dynamic memory allocators malloc() and free()?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, real-time, dynamic-memory-allocation, cpu-architecture

I am curious about calculating Worst Case Execution Time of a real-time system and I am trying to find extreme scenarios to predict a worst case time.

What type of input scenarios would slow down the dynamic memory allocation? Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea how to approach that without functional and performance specs and constraints.  For example, if your design relied on buffer pools located at startup, subsequent 'malloc style' dynamic allocation might be avoided altogether.

Comment: In multithreaded programs freeing a pointer from a different thread than made the allocation can be bad. As well for a given size class freeing in reverse sorted order wont play nice with the skip list I think.

Comment: 'freeing a pointer from a different thread than made the allocation can be bad', how?  Even if that was true, it couldn't be nearly as bad as signaling the pointer back to the thread that allocated it, (assuming that thread is even known by the recipient).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free-list being empty would be one case, needing new memory from the OS.  The free-list being huge but filled with small blocks too small to satisfy the current request would be another: could trigger walking a big list before finding one, or falling back to another way of getting new memory.

So obviously you'd want to design an allocator's data structures to avoid that problem, perhaps by grouping free lists by size, especially when real-time worst case is a concern.

That's just off the top of my head, and not something I've been involved with designing, so it's certainly not an exhaustive list.